# nmap unable to find nmap-services

Tags: java, android, nmap

In some Android devices i got this erros :

```
Unable to find nmap-services! Resorting to /etc/services
Unable to open /etc/services for reading service information
```

This happen with `Android 8, 8.1 and Android P`

In lower versions it is working well

I'm using precompiled binaries V. 7.31 from : https://github.com/kost/nmap-android/releases

I have read too about nmap `--datadir` but can't make it works.
Any Idea ?

P.s : The tests performed on Emulators and Real devices too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by copying Nmap extra data like "services,scripts etc. into main nmap binary directory"

Answer (score 2):

Have you rooted your device? It looks like the operating system does not allow `nmap` to open `/etc/services`.It might be that the file can be open by root user only or its read only.

Comment: Solved by copying Nmap extra datas "services,scripts etc. into nmap binary directory"

Answer (score 0):

This answer fixes error:

`Unable to find nmap-services! Resorting to /etc/services/`

I copied everything from folder: `/usr/share/nmap` from a computer that had `nmap` installed correctly to another computer that didn't have nmap installed correctly.

*Additional Notes:*

1. If you receive this error, fixing it is definitely worth it as **your scans will be way faster**.  My scan time went from about 120 seconds to 5 seconds.
2. I also had `nmap` binary installed to `/usr/bin/nmap`.  If your receiving this error, it means you already have the nmap binary installed.